# Mysql Replace dont work fine in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, replace

i am trying to do this through php , i have this query

```
update table set fieldname =replace(fieldname,'Ã©','é');
```

this return me 0 records affected

this don't work, but if i do this directly from mysql front or php myadmin , that works

i have this problems only with those characters , for others text work fine,i'm copy from php echo and paste into mysql front and works!!

please if you have any suggestion to solve my problem,i would appreciate it

regards

Comment: did u try replacing other character? try to replace normal characters. Probably this is just about those `special characters`

Comment: yep it's only with those special chars like Ã with something else

Comment: `$value= htmlentities($_POST['value'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` try this is only a example. in short where every you are setting the value set it like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this is the perfect answer or not.
This is the problem of `charset`. Do not update your text in database. When you `select` it from db and store it in a variable, convert the encoding of that variable :

`$var = mb_convert_encoding($var,'ISO-8859-15','utf-8');`

I tried this, and it worked!

Comment: thank you!!, i'm try this in local server and works fine

regards